# Requests from XMLDom to retrieve XML from API are blocked

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2010, vba

I've written a macro in VBA for Excel 2010 to retrieve data from an API that returns XML. I'm doing this voluntarily to help my wife and her colleagues from doing a lot of manual work. So, the macro is used in an enterprise setting, where security settings are out of my hands and having never worked in an enterprise setting, I also have no idea what the possibilities are.

However, the IT guys have stated they are willing to help, but have no idea how to fix it. So I wonder if anyone here can point in the right direction on how to get this to work on all PCs.

The code is as below, and it works on the home PCs of all my wife's colleagues and my own too. It also works on some work PCs, but on some not. The code fails on the `objDoc.Load` part, it shows my error message:

```
MsgBox ("There was an error when connecting to the API)
```

I wonder if there are enterprise settings, or individual Excel settings that block access to external URLs in macros. I wouldn't be surprised, as it would be good security, but I guess there should also be a way to whitelist the url of the API?

Does anyone have an idea how this could be fixed? Either in the code, in Excel 2010 settings or any Office enterprise settings I'm not aware of?

```
Dim strUrl as String
Dim objDoc As Object
Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objDoc.async = False

strUrl = {api URL}

    If objDoc.Load(strUrl) Then
        'it worked!
    Else
        MsgBox ("There was an error when connecting to the API)
        Exit Function
    End If
```

Comment: Have you tried, on the failing machine(s) to use an API tester and see what message you get back?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach by narrowing the error field**

Apparently your code using late binding is executed, but displays an error message. Often XML code contains non readable character entities (e.g. ampersands `&`).
You can narrow the error field by replacing the complete `Else` block in your code with the following statements:

```
  Dim xPE        As Object    ' Set xPE = CreateObject("MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError")
  Dim strErrText As String
  Set xPE = objDoc.parseError
  With xPE
     strErrText = "Load error " & .ErrorCode & " xml file " & vbCrLf & _
      Replace(.URL, "file:///", "") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      xPE.reason & _
      "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      "Line No.:    " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
      "Line Pos.: " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
      "File Pos.:  " & .filepos & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
  End With
  MsgBox strErrText, vbExclamation
  Set xPE = Nothing
  Exit Function
```

**Additional hint**

If you set your `objDoc` object to memory with `Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")` generally you are getting an older version (3.0), so in most cases it's preferrable to use explicitly `Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` instead to get the latest 6.0 version.

Comment: @JanWillem - did my approach to narrow the error field by an Extended load function help?